# Getting the "ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show" error if redirect_to "status:" parameter is not set to ":see_other"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I am following the tutorial from [RailsGuides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) (Rails version is `7.0.2`). Whenever I click on the destroy button, the page sends a `GET` request to `/articles/:id`, instead of the `root_path` that I've set to . Alternatively, I have also tried `articles_path`, but does not fix the issue.

This error is resolved, when I use the `status:` parameter, and set it to `:see_other`. This was not the case in older versions of Rails (v4, v6).

This does not work:

```rb
  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to root_path
    # [ redirect_to articles_path ] does not work as well.
  end
```

This works:

```rb
  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to root_path, status: :see_other
    # [ redirect_to articles_path, status: :see_other ] will works fine too.
  end
```

Can someone explain the reason for this behaviour?

Edit: After a little bit of research in the issues section of Rails repo, I found this  [Deleting article in section 6.5 of getting started guide doesn't work #43429](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/43429) . From my understanding, maybe this was caused by a bug currently in Turbo-Rails ?

Answer (score 2):

This is super interesting and I had to dig into the ActionController docs to find anything helpful.

In the [Rails API `redirect_to` documentation](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to), they state:

> If you are using XHR requests other than GET or POST and redirecting after the request then some browsers will follow the redirect using the original request method. This may lead to undesirable behavior such as a double DELETE. To work around this you can return a 303 See Other status code which will be followed using a GET request.

Your controller's `#destroy` action should be making a DELETE request, which is included in the "other than" list mentioned in the above documentation. So it seems likely you are experiencing their example exactly! When you do not include a `:status`, the browser makes a double DELETE request. And since the first DELETE request deleted the record, the second DELETE request will try to delete a record that no longer exists, and return that `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error.

Comment: I did a little bit of research on the GitHub repository of Rails, and found an issue that matches what I was talking about (link in the post). What do you think?

Comment: Good find! That sounds identical to your issue. And the "fix" was to update the tutorial docs to set the `turbo_method`. I'm super curious if that solves the issue for you, have you tried it? https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43941/files

Comment: Yes, the tutorial works just fine. Just that I was confused when I saw that my tutorial app wasn't working when I subconsciously did it the way it used to work in earlier version of Rails.